# Playground Execution error: Signal SIGABRT while parsing JSON string

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm really not sure why the JSON parsing causes a SIGABRT error.

```
class Bug {
    enum State {
        case open
        case closed
    }

    let state: State
    let timestamp: Date
    let comment: String

    init(state: State, timestamp: Date, comment: String) {
        self.state = state
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.comment = comment
    }

    init(jsonString: String) throws {

        let dict = convertToDictionary(from: jsonString)
```

I think this is what is causing the error but I couldn't figure out why:

```
        self.state = dict["state"] as! Bug.State

        self.comment = dict["comment"] as! String

        self.timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as! Date
    }
}
```

JSON string to dictionary:

```
func convertToDictionary(from text: String) -> [String: Any] {
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return [:] }
    let anyResult: Any? = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    return anyResult as? [String: Any] ?? [:]
}

enum TimeRange {
    case pastDay
    case pastWeek
    case pastMonth
}
```

Error image: [image]

Answer (score 2):

This line appears to be a problem:

`self.state = dict["state"] as! Bug.State`

`Bug.State` is a custom type of `enum`.  But the value in `dict["state"]` is a `String`.  by using `as!` you are telling the compiler that you **know** that will be a `Bug.State` at runtime, but when the system looks while the app is running it finds out that it is a String which is **not** a `Bug.State` so it throws an exception.

Similarly on the line that sets the timestamp you are trying to convert what is probably a string into a date using straight type casting.  You are going to have to use an NSDateFormatter to extract the date from the string to covert that value into a String.

Comment: Ok, what changes do you think I should make in order to solve this?

Comment: I would add a constructor to your enum that accepts a string and returns a properly created enum value.  Then you you could call something like `self.state = Bug.State(fromString: dict["state"])`

Comment: I don't think thats the problem though. All three self.xxx statements cause this error.

Comment: The middle one, setting the comment, should be fine.  The last one shows you have a similar misunderstanding of how type casting operators work  I've updated my answer with some additional information about how you should handle the conversion of a String to a Date.